# WordPress root directory favicon file access

Tags: wordpress, directory, root, favicon

I am a junior WordPress developer.
My website favicon is present in the root directory on my WordPress website, & I want to access it by path like `mywebsite.com/myfavicon.ico`
when I visit this, it gives me a `404 error`

I have added favicon to my website via customizer and added a link to the header file too, favicon is working fine on my website but I want to make this link live `mywebsite.com/myfavicon.ico`, please guide me on how can I make this link live.

Comment: You should use proper file location for example in fav file are locate in uploads folder then you should <?php echo site_url(). '/wp-content/uploads/myfavicon.ico' ?>

Answer (score 0):

The path of files and folders in WordPress is as follows

```
site.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/favicon.png
```

To view this path, take a look at the inspect element main page of your site and follow `<link>` tag in the head.

then you see path of favicon file .

If you want it to be exactly the way you specify it, you need to place the favicon file in the `public-html` directory .
upload file on your site panel, cPanel or Direct Admin, and place the file in the `public-html`

then you can see file in this path

```
site.com/favicon.png
```